# Not displaying nested values in Angular app

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a locally stored JSON file which then has a service which send through the following data set

```
[  
   {  
      "id":"73c624c9-6db7-4fd2-ac91-c1084aee0565",
      "etl":362,
      "subject":"Temp Subject",
      "body":"Temp Body",
      "deliveryAddress":"test@test.com",
      "accountNumber":"12345",
      "deliveryChannel":"EMAIL",
      "attachments":[  
         {  
            "id":"1",
            "attachToDeliveryMessage":false,
            "fileName":"12345-ITM-2019-01-25.pdf",
            "passwordProtected":true,
            "attachmentType":"ITEMISED_BILLING",
            "renderSucceeded":true,
            "renderError":null,
            "link":{  
               "href":"linky"
            }
         },
         {  
            "id":"2",
            "attachToDeliveryMessage":true,
            "fileName":"12345-INV-27608011279-2019-01-25.pdf",
            "passwordProtected":true,
            "attachmentType":"INVOICE",
            "renderSucceeded":true,
            "renderError":null,
            "link":{  
               "href":"linky"
            }
         }
      ],
      "renderSucceeded":true,
      "renderError":null
   },
]
```

I can successfully display the outer values but am having difficulty in displaying the nested values like "attachments"

Here is my HTML

```
<div class="card-body" *ngFor="let item of customerAccountDocs">
  <p>{{item.id}}</p>
  <p>{{item.accountNumber}}
  <p>{{item.etl}}
  <p>{{item.subject}}
  <p>{{item.body}}
  <p>{{item.deliveryAddress}}
  <p>{{item.deliveryChannel}}
  <p *ngFor="let item of customerAccountDocs.attachments">{{item.id}}</p>
</div>
```

Please assist me. I am just using bootstrap to display the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be iterating over `item.attachments` instead of `customerAccountDocs.attachments`

```
<div class="card-body" *ngFor="let item of customerAccountDocs">
  <p>{{item.id}}</p>
  <p>{{item.accountNumber}}
  <p>{{item.etl}}
  <p>{{item.subject}}
  <p>{{item.body}}
  <p>{{item.deliveryAddress}}
  <p>{{item.deliveryChannel}}
  <p *ngFor="let attachment of item.attachments">{{attachment.id}}</p>
</div>
```